# Additional logon information required

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I am connecting to a wireless network in a company and as the title says, I am getting the message that I have to log in to the network.

To do that I usually just open a random webpage and I am redirected to the login page which in turn redirects me to the original page after authentication.

I have 2 questions:

1. This does not seem to be the case when https:// is used in the random page. Is there a reason for that?
2. The networks expires my connection every 2 hours. At that time I have to relog. Most of the times I simply open a new web page and am redirected to the login page. Other times no matter how many times I do this, no matter if I disconnect and reconnect to the network, I cannot get the login page to show. I have to restart my PC for it to happen. Any clues as to why? Or what I can do to get that page  to show?

Comment: 1. Yes only http pages will redirect to logon page, the wireless AP only knows how to redirect port 80 to the logon page

Comment: We have the same at my workplace but the timeout is 9hrs (a day, basically). We run Cisco APs with their various controllers and a RADIUS server to authenticate against AD. In particular, with the Cisco kit, is (to get the login page) when you request an SSL enabled page (https) the controllers can't redirect the page. This caused us problems where people had Google as their homepage and they moved to default SSL. This is fixed in a firmware update if you use Cisco kit. Talk to your network admins.

Comment: Ideally, your network admins should consider different networks for staff and guests. Staff shouldn't ever be "expired" and guests should remain with the 2hr session. That's just my opinion as it keeps staff happy.

Comment: Well this company is a client of the company I work for, so typically I am guest and I am using the guest network. And yes, they are using Cisco. Is there a way to find out the exact page that I am redirected to? The url reads `1.1.1.1./login.html` but that does not work every time.